# python, aiostream: reorder elements of async sequence as soon as they are received

Tags: python, asynchronous, flatten

Given a `aiostream` async sequence and an acync function `func` I wish to reorder the sequence (convert to another async aiostream sequence) according to the job finishing time. For eaample:

```py
import aiostream
import asyncio

async def async_func(x):
    await asyncio.sleep(1 - 0.2 * x)
    return x

s = aiostream.stream.iterate(range(5))
s_mapped = aiostream.stream.map(s, async_func)

s_reordered = ???(s_mapped)

await aiostream.stream.list(s_reordered)
# [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

(this is needed for downstream chunk operation)

**This does not work:**

1. `aiostream.stream.merge` takes a sync generator but not async aiostream sequence.
2. `aiostream.stream.flatten` according to the docs realize the expected operation for a sequence of sequences but but not for a sequence. However, simple conversion with `aiostream.stream.just` provides unexpected result:

```py
s_flatten = aiostream.stream.flatten(aiostream.stream.map(s_mapped, aiostream.stream.just))
await aiostream.stream.list(s_flatten)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Update and solution:**
As it is mentioned by @python_user below
`aiostream.stream.map(s, async_func, ordered=False)`
solves the problem.

Comment: `aiostream.stream.map(s, async_func, ordered=False)` seem to give what you want

Comment: "This argument (ordered=False) is ignored if the provided function is synchronous."

Comment: `async_func` is not sync, so I do not get what you are implying

Comment: You are right @python_user, `aiostream.stream.map(s, async_func, ordered=False)` solves the problem. Thank you! However, still wondering why the solution with `flatten` does not work.